# how to export two MS ACCESS table into one csv file without getting overwritten?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I am trying to export two MS Access table into one .csv file. I am not able to do so, i am able export these two table into two different csv files. I need both tables to get exported into one csv file. Both tables having different numbers of columns.

Table1 has follwing columns

```
f1, f2, f3, f4, f5
```

table2 is having

```
t1, t2, t3, t4
```

I am trying to import through vb in this manner but not able to append two tables into this query. 
 I tried to import in this following manner

```
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "table1", "t1.csv", True

DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "table2", "t1.csv", False
```

But i am getting file with records of table2 only. I am not able to append two tables into one export query so that i can get desired result

From table1 i want headers only and from table2 i need only data to be exported. 
Is there any way in MS Access i can get headers from table1 and records from table2 into one csv file

Answer (score 4):

Great question! A lot of times I will **create a query first**, which contains all the output, just like I want in my final output file. Then I will use a single `DoCmd.TransferText` command to output my query to the CSV file.

If you are joining data from two tables together, you will use what is called a **Union Query**. This can be a little more confusing to create because you need to type in the SQL yourself instead of dragging and dropping in the visual query editor. But once you get the hang of it, it is not as complicated as it might seem.

I am going to make some assumptions here, and give you an example of how this might work. Let's say `table1` only has one row, and these are the headers you want in your output file:

```
select f1 as t1, f2 as t2, f3 as t3, f4 as t4, f5 as t5
from table1
union select t1, t2, t3, t4, '' as t5
from table2
```

The key factor is that both tables we are merging together in this union query are using the *same column names*. That's why we use `f1 as t1`. This makes the `f1` column use `t1` as its column name (commonly called an alias).

Also notice how in `table2`, we don't have a `t5` column, so we just use an empty string and alias it as `t5`. This allows the columns to match what we have in `table1`, even though `table2` has no data for this column.

When you view this query, you will notice that the header row is in a random place in the query results. We want to make sure it ends up as the top row in the query, so let's add another column so we can sort the results and force the header to the top row.

```
select f1 as t1, f2 as t2, f3 as t3, f4 as t4, f5 as t5, 0 as mysort
from table1
union select t1, t2, t3, t4, '' as t5, 1 as mysort
from table2
order by mysort;
```

Beautiful! Now the header is in the top row! Now we can run our export command, and dump the results into a CSV file:

```
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim,,"qryExample","myfile.csv", False
```

If you don't want the sort order column in your output file, then simply nest the union query inside another query where the `mysort` column is not included.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the answer buddy, i just want to ask one think that t5 column from table2 will give null values while exporting file??

Comment: that query giving me mysort column also while i am trying to export. I need header from first table and data from second table

Comment: @ravichaudhary - You mention that you need the header from the first table. Does this mean you want your header columns to be `f1`, `f2`, `f3`, etc... or that `table1` contains _data_ that you want to use as the headers in your export file? My examples assumed you wanted _data_ outputed as the header row.